# How to get time elapsed and time remaining from api radionomy current song

Tags: php, api, time

I have a url: 
http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=dba94474-bd22-468d-bbe3-cc2c32c3220c&type=xml&cover=yes&callmeback=yes&defaultcover=yes&streamurl=yes&zoneid=0&countrycode=&size=90&dynamicconf=yes&cachbuster=144626

I have start time: `2015-02-18 20:46:44.213`
and duration of a song: `120000`

How do I get time elapsed and time remaining?

EDIT:

code:

```
 $data = simplexml_load_file('http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=dba94474-bd22-468d-bbe3-cc2c32c3220c&type=xml&cover=yes&callmeback=yes&defaultcover=yes&streamurl=yes&zoneid=0&countrycode=&size=90&dynamicconf=yes&cachbuster=144626');
 $currentSong = $data->track;
 print_r ( $currentSong );
 $song = $currentSong->title . ' - ' . $currentSong->artists;
 $startTime = $currentSong->starttime;
 $songDuration = $currentSong->playduration;

 $dateTime = new DateTime( $startTime );
 $timeStampStart = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
 $timeNow = time();

 $timeElapsed = ($timeStampStart - $timeNow);

 $timeLeft = ($songDuration - $timeElapsed);

 $ar = array( "song" => $song, "elapsedTime" => $timeElapsed, "timeLeft" => $timeLeft);
 print_r ( $ar );
```

result : http://haddoz.li/api/radio/currentsong

Answer (score 0):

Convert that start time into a unix timestamp.

Get the current time as a unix timestamp.

Subtract start time from current time.

This difference is the elapsed time (in milliseconds).

Subtract that from the duration.

This second difference will be the time remaining.